# magento page not display properly

Tags: magento, layout

I install magento on the server with default theme, then I put in a category and a product to see how it works, I found out the detail page doesnt layout right and no pictures on it only plain texts. I change to other themes and reindex / refresh coach and none of them helped, the magento is fresh install and nothing change beside adding some theme and product.

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall if it isn't a huge problem. Something must have gone wonky.